# Mapping class group of $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

If I recall correctly from a lecture I attended the last year we have that
$MCG(\mathbb{S^2})\simeq\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$ by Smale in the 60' and $MCG(\mathbb{S^3})\simeq\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$ as well for a result by Hatcher in the 80'. 
I cannot find any reference though, especially for the last result (maybe I recall wrong).

Here I am taking as definition of the $MCG$ the group of diffeomorphism modulo smooth isotopies.

Moreover, I wonder what we know about mapping class groups of spheres in higher dimension and other manifolds in general. For sure  $MCG(\mathbb{S}^6)$ can't be just $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$ because of the exotic $\mathbb{S}^7$, am I right?

Comment: This is a theorem of Cerf long before Hatcher proved the more general fact about homotopy type of the diffeomorphism group. In high dimensions, the oriented mapping class group of $S^n$ is the same as the group of exotic spheres one dimension up. This follows from Cerf's pseudoisotopy theorem.

Comment: If you define $MCG(M)$ as $\pi_0(Diff(M))$, then relevant references are at  https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single definition of MCG, and especially it might depend on the kind of maps used (homeomorphisms, or diffeomorphisms, the class of differentiability possibly mattering, and the class of differentiability of the isotopy maybe as well)